# How do you see if a tile was watered?

Tags: harvest-moon-magical-melody

I am using Dolphin to play this game and I cannot see a difference between tiles that have been watered and tiles that have been not watered that day.

[image: Watering crops]

The blue tiles have been watered (at least I think they have been), the red ones not. But there is no visual difference as opposed to the Playstation version of the game.

**How can I tell if I watered a tile successfully?**

Comment: Emulation is fine and on topic, [here is the discussion on meta.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102/whats-the-official-stance-on-console-emulation)

Comment: @Jason_c_o I own Back To Nature and other Games of this series legitimately. So no piracy here.

Comment: The center field 2nd row from the top looks not watered, or is this crop just on an other growing level?

Answer (score 2):

With no tools or objects in your hands, click on the crop (as if you were to water it). It'll tell you the stage it's at.

I haven't got the game at this point in time but if i remember correctly that should work, i remember dealing with this myself at one point and either this was the answer or it was just simply that in this version there is absolutely know way of knowing without making a physical note of it.

Comment: How do you click on a crop on a GameCube?

Comment: Same way that you would normally water it just without any tools in your hand. Like i said i haven't played in a long time. probably not since gamecube was the height of nintendo tech

Comment: Having looked into this further unfortunately on the Gamecube this is the only option and thus in Dolphin emulation it is as well. I have tested everything else i could think of and checked thoroughly for graphical signs but have found nothing. but this does work to tell you if a crop is still growing